# How to stop Site from Scraping my site

Tags: .htaccess, web

I have this songs site what ever data it has same is being displayed in other site 
even if i echo "hello"  same is done on other site  does any body know how can i prevent that
just getting in more depth i found out that site is using file_get_contents() how can i prevent him from doing that

Comment: Suing them would be the best option, if possible

Comment: I get some Forex infos from a site and when they recognize that they changed the code and load info via js.

Comment: You could still get the info if you bothered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said file_get_contents was being used.

`A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.`

To disable them, more information is at http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Edit: If they go and use CURL or an equivalent after this, try and mess with their script by changing the HTML layout, etc. If that doesn't help, try and locate the IP of the script host, and make it return nonsense ;)

Edit2: If they use an iframe use javascript to redirect on iframe detection

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try to dermine their IP address and block it

Comment: Most crawlers that I know do not use dynamic IP's. They might rotate them but they are run from server enviroments, not your typical domestic line

Comment: I agree with this solution, just block their IPs or ranges.  They will eventually run out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can even generate rubbish information just for that crawler, just to mess the "clone" site.

The first question to be answered is: Have you identified the crawler getting the information from your site?

If so, then you can give anything you want to this process: Nothing (ignore / block), a message telling the owners to stop getting your information, give them back rubbish contents, ...

Anyway, the first step is doing things properly. Be sure that you site has a "robots.txt" with the accepted policy for crawlers.